How to say this
I received an email from this company, in which they proposed a job to me. I sent them an email saying that I would like to work with them. After 3 months I haven’t yet received any email from them. Now, I am writing a follow up email. I want to ask them a response, and want to know if they saw my email. After all, it might have ended up in their spam folder! And I think I deserve a response, anyway,
My question is if the phrases “in the first place” or “at all” can convey my intention. Or maybe there are better phrases in such contexts?

Could you please let me know what you think, and if you got my email
in the first place?
Could you please let me know what you think, and if you got my email
at all?


To me, it is on topic if someone asks how to word something correctly in English, but the content is counterproductive. A job proposed to you without applying is only a job lead, not an offer. That's why you had to say you "would like to work with them." I agree you deserve a response, but you cannot expect one today, in fact. So telling them what you deserve can make you look needy. Or demanding.

Discussion about proper communication with a prospective employer would be more appropriate for [workplace.se].

Was it the company or an agency fishing for leads? Do you imagine you were head-hunted? I've had spam emails saying I am needed for a job, but it's just an agency casting their net. But very many employment applications go unanswered anyway – into the bin, with respect to yourself. If they didn't answer just forget it.
